# Change the table's binding

Tags: sapui5

I need to change the binding of my table when i click on a button and it is working when the table is not empty but if the table is empty it is not working

i tried this solution(because the table is already defined in xml) and it is partially working

```
    oTable.bindItems("/CarsSet", oTable.getItems()[0].clone(), null);
```

the problem is when the table is empty it is not working since oTable.getItems()[0] is undefined

Comment: Why do you need to clone the first item? If you just bind the path only it should work.

Comment: @TiiJ7 no it shows an error : missing template also i tried with bindaggregation() but not working

Answer (score 0):

one cheap solution is to clone the first element template and save the reference when the Table has been rendered the first time. After that you can use it when you change the binding otherwise (if the table is empty) you will get that error.

Answer (score 0):

The template item should be defined in the `dependents` aggregation. This way you can always clone it regardless of the state of the binding.

You can refer to [this](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/284a036c8ff943238fb65bf5a2676fb7) sample to check how `dependents` works.